Need help with this inequality dilema
First time here and I need help with this situation what I am doing wrong.
Let's say $a < x < b$ where $x$ is the unknown.
Now please tell me at which step I am doing wrong.
$$\begin{align}
\phantom{-}2a < \phantom{-}2x < \phantom{-}2b &\qquad \text{multiplied by $2$}\\
-2b < -2x < -2a &\qquad \text{multiplied by $(-1)$, so reversed the order}
\end{align}$$
$$a < x < b$$
$$-2b < -2x < -2a$$
$$a-2b < -x  < 2b-a$$
Which leads to a completely different result.
Example:
$$\begin{align}
2<\phantom{-2}x<\phantom{-}4 \tag1\\
 4 < \phantom{-}2x <\phantom{-}8 \tag2\\
-8< -2x < -4 \tag3\\
 2< \phantom{-2}x < \phantom{-}4 \tag4\\
 -6 < \;\;-x < \phantom{-}0 &\quad\text{added (3) and (4)}\tag5\\
 0 < \phantom{-2}x < \phantom{-}6 &\quad\text{which is different than $2<x<4$} \tag6
\end{align}$$
I know that my operation is wrong but can't find the mistake. Any help is appreciated.

Please use mathjax to edit your question. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

If $x$ is between $2$ and $4$, it is also between $0$ and $6$.

Typo just before "Which leads to a completely different result": it should be $b-2a$. Apart from this, everything is correct. It is true that $a<x<b$ implies $a-2b<-x<b-2a$.
Another way to prove it is adding $-b<-x<-a$ and $a-b<0<b-a$.

Another way to get from $a<x<b$ to $2a-b<x<2b-a$ is to add $(b-a)$ (a positive number) to the right-hand side, making it bigger; and to subtract $(b-a)$ from the left-hand side, making it smaller. The second inequality is different, but it's valid.

@Blue True, but these are not the inequalities proved by the OP. Instead, see my previous comment.

@AnneBauval: "these are not the inequalities proved by the OP" ... I should've been clearer. ... OP indicates that $a-2b<-x<b-2a$ (fixing a presumed typo on the right-hand side) "leads to" a problem. The example carries the manipulations through one more step to leave $x$ alone in the center, noting the difference between the final form and the original. Taking OP's symbolic inequality to its final form gives $2a-b<x<2b-a$. While this is "completely different" from $a<x<b$, it can be more-directly obtained from that original by adding $b-a$ to the right and subtracting $b-a$ from the left.

Ok, thank you..

The second inequality indicates that x can be 5 while the initial statement says otherwise. They can't be both true.

@EnginDemir: "The second inequality indicates that x can be 5 while the initial statement says otherwise. They can't be both true." You've shown that if the first inequality is true, then the second is true (albeit arguably less helpful :). That the converse ("if the second, then the first") is false doesn't invalidate the logic. (Statements and their converses often have opposite truth values.) ... What you've demonstrated is that manipulating inequalities as you did doesn't create an equivalent inequality, just a valid one (in the context of the original).

Thanks. This was actually an engineering problem. I simplified the question for clarity. I personally came to the latest (wider) conclusion which didn't yield correct results. İs there a way to avoid that?

You should include implication signs explicitly, which would clarify what is going on. What you have is that $(1) \Leftrightarrow (2) \Leftrightarrow (3) , (4) \Rightarrow (5) \Leftrightarrow (6)$. So you do not have double implication throughout. It is true that $ 2 < x < 4 \Rightarrow 0 < x < 6$. $\quad$ You have not shown that $ 0 < x < 6 \Rightarrow 2 < x < 4$ (and will not be able to show it as it is not a true statement).
